# AngularJS code doesn't update to cshtml?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a demo project in ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS. I have a directive called 'testSomething', it worked at first. But after I made some changes, the cshtml page still shows the previous directive, my IDE is Visual Studio for Mac. Any ideas?

**My AngularJS directive code**

```
app.directive('testSomething', function () {
    var notes = {};    
    notes.restrict = 'E';
    notes.template = "@Display()";  //Display() will return a string          
    return notes;
});
```

**My cshtml page**

```
<div data-ng-controller="forumCtrl">
    <test-something></test-something>
</div>
```

Comment: what changes are you expecting? `cshtml` is a source file, do you mean the generated html?

Answer (score 0):

Place your directive outside the controller,

```
 app.directive('testSomething', function () {
    var notes = {};    
    notes.restrict = 'E';
    notes.template = "@Display()";  //Display() will return a string          
    return notes;
});

app.controller("forumCtrl", function ($scope) {   
});
```

Comment: That was a mistake when I copy and paste the code, the directive is outside of controller